# Show that A is an algebra

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $X$ is a collection of sets and $Ω$ element of $X$. Also $A$, $B$ are elements of $X$. Then, $A-B=A\cap B^c$ element in $X$. Show that $X$ is an algebra.

Please help me, how I can show this question.

I know that I need to show the following:

- If $A$ in $X$ then $A^c$ in $X$.
- If $A$, $B$ in $X$, then $A\cup B$ in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of $A$ is the difference of $\Omega$ and $A$, so $A^c$ belongs to $X$ if $A$ does.

Given $A,B\in X$ we therefore also have that
$$
A^c-B=(A^c\cap B^c)=(A\cup B)^c
$$
and hence $A\cup B$ belongs to $X$.